# Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: Object required

Tags: ajax, wicket

I just spent several hours of my life debugging this problem. I'm documenting it here for others.

**Question:**

I'm getting the following error when I try to click on an `AjaxLink` in Internet Explorer:

`Wicket: ERROR: Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: Object required`

It works fine in all other browsers; just IE is busted.

Comment: I faced some other kind of that:  Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: Method Not Allowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check to make sure that your HTML is 100% syntactically correct. Ajax responses are returned to the browser inside a `CDATA` section, and if the payload is not well-formed, IE will sometimes choke.

In my case I neglected to close a `<link>` tag in the `<head>` section. Simply closing that link tag made all the difference.

Aside: if you ever come across a tough-to-solve problem in Wicket, it's a good idea to create a [quickstart project](http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html) that reproduces your issue. It can be a lot of work to boil things down, but in doing so you often find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I want to note one more potential reason for the issue with Wicket's AJAX in IE. It might help someone, who encounters similar problem.

In my case I had the following error message in IE:

```
Wicket: ERROR: Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: could not find root <ajax-response> element
```

The reason was an incorrect Content-Type of AJAX response. I used AbstractTransformerBehavior and there was a bug in Wicket 1.4.x so this behavior was rewriting response Content-Type with text/html. IE does not parse such response as XML.